# "Kernel attack" on MinRank -- why do we guess $\left\lceil \frac k n \right\rceil$ vectors?

Tags: cryptanalysis

The kernel attack on MinRank is described [here (page 5)](http://www-polsys.lip6.fr/~jcf/Papers/crypto08.pdf). My question refers to this line:

> Note that if $m = \left\lceil \frac k n \right\rceil$, the system essentially has only one solution $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_k)$.

Why is this so? I understand that when $m = \left\lceil \frac k n \right\rceil$ the described system is never underdetermined, but how does this help? Any insight / further references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we have $k+1$ matrices $M_0, M_1, \ldots, M_k \in \mathbb{K}^{n\times{}n}$. We are trying to find weights $\mu_1, \dots, \mu_k$ such that the rank of the weighted sum of matrices is smaller than or equal to some target rank: $\mathsf{rank}(-M_0 + \sum_{i=1}^k\mu_iM_i) \leq r$.

The Courtois and Goubin strategy is to select $m$ random vectors $\mathbf{x}^{(i)} \in \mathbb{K}^n$ (for $i$ from $1$ to $m$) and hope they all lie in the kernel of some combination of the matrices. If these vectors do lie in the kernel of suck a weighted sum, we can then easily find those weights by solving for $\mu = (\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_k)$ the linear system
$ \left\{ (-M_0 + \sum_{j=1}^k\mu_jM_j)\mathbf{x}^{(i)} = \mathbf{0} \right\} $
for all
$ i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$.

This linear system consists of $mn$ equations and $k$ variables. If $k = mn$, then we expect there to be one solution. If $k < mn$, then the system might well be over-determined and might not admit any solutions, whereas if $k > mn$ then we might find *several* solutions rather than a single one. We are aiming for the case in which the system has one solution, so we must choose $m$ so that $k \approx mn$ holds as well as possible. Further constraints on $m$ are that it is an integer -- so we must round up or down -- and that it is different from zero -- because otherwise we have no equations. So the natural choice is $m = \lceil {k \over n} \rceil$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I suspected that was the reason to choose $m = \left\lceil \frac k n \right\rceil$, but figured I'd better ask. Would any problems arise if $M_0 = 0$ (the zero matrix, giving us a homogeneous), aside from the fact that $\lambda = \vec{0}$ would be a solution?

Comment: The original paper by Courtois and Goubin does not mention an $M_0$ matrix that *is* included in the sum but without being weighted. The only reason I can think of why the authors of the paper you cite introduce this constraint is, like you say, to prevent "all weights are zero" from emerging as a solution.

Comment: What confuses me is that, as you said, in the original paper, we basically get a homogeneous system, which either has a trivial solution, or infinitely many, irregardless of whether it's over- or underdetermined. Yet, they still choose $\left\lceil \frac k n \right\rceil$ vectors. Why would it be so?

Comment: Well, now that I think about it, choosing $\left\lceil \frac k n \right\rceil$ vectors makes sense in a homogeneous system, as an underdetermined homogeneous system will always have infinitely many solutions. This is not the case with a possibly overdetermined one. And, if we don't want the zero vector as a solution, we can simply ignore it (the so-called trivial solution). Let me know what you think.

Comment: In most MQ systems, $k \leq n$ so that $m$ is essentially always equal to 1.